# Why Won't My Macro/VB run from in my PowerPoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm trying to add a little interaction to a PowerPoint presentation I'm working on. I'm written a little VB that will increase the size and position a particular chart object when the script runs.  I'm tested the script in design mode and everything seems to work fine.  When, however, I link my code to an action button and try to run it from within the slide show the code does not run.  I do most of my VB in Excel so I have not run across this before. Can anyone suggest a fix for this. My code is set forth below:

```
 Sub MoveChart23()
    Dim s
    For Each s In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes
     If s.Name = "Chart 23" Then
      s.Top = 50
      s.Width = 620
      s.Left = 50
      s.Height = 400
     End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: you gonna do a kind of animation that way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, I think your problem is in the following line:

```
For Each s In ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes
```

while you have no Selection in presentation mode. Depending on the way you run and control the whole presentation you should use something like this instead:

```
For Each s In ActiveWindow.Slides(1).Shapes
```

But if you need to refer to currently viewed slide you should go this way:

```
For Each s In SlideShowWindows(1).View.Slide.Shapes
```